# How the random numbers were generated which were used during world war 2(ww2)?

Tags: cryptology

I know [One-time-pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) were used during ww2 and, I want to know how the random numbers were generated.

Comment: See [How were one-time pads and keys historically generated?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/55283) on Cryptography SE, [Random number table: history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_table#History) and [SIGSALY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSALY). Most of them were not random in the mathematical sense, and used erratic typists, telephone directories, logarithmic tables or compendiums of unrelated words. Kendall's and Babington-Smith's light flashing machine, and SIGSALY's random noise were probably most satisfactory.

Comment: Have you got examples how they were used?

Comment: @Conifold What is random in the mathematical sense? An ideal form of randomness? Platonic randomness?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder [Algorithmically random sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence).

Comment: @Conifold Isnt an algorithm at odds with pure probability?

Comment: Maybe they were generated by throwing dices. A fabric hall full of throwers to save the country...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US Patent [2406031](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/dc/40/14/2ec5d3d4b6bb03/US2406031.pdf), filed on 21 May 1942, issued on 20 Aug 1946, describes one such technology:  A hopper feeds a jumble of transparent and opaque beads past  a photocell array.  The beads are fed back into the hopper, and the data read from the photocells ends up on a punched tape.

I don't know if this particular invention was used in practice, but it seems likely to me that something along these lines was used to produce the one-time keying material (the bulk of which was for use with teleprinters) for US forces in the war.